Get the user's group from IAP
I would like to configure IAP to grant a different level of access based on who is logged in. Then I create several groups that will ensure that I can manage the type of profiling on the application.
When I extract the return header from IAP I only have these values:

aud,su,identity_source,azp,exp,hd,iat,email

I extract these values ​​from Authentication like this:
Jwt jwt = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();
Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry  : claims.entrySet()) {
     String key = entry.getKey();
     Object value = entry.getValue();
     logger.info(key + " : " + value.toString());
}

What I would like is for example:

UserX from the admin-iap group can interact with all the features of the application
UserY from the developer-iap group can only see some pages of the application
UserZ ecc...

In addition to the group, is it possible to extract some user information, for example Name and Surname?
Is it possible to test IAP authentication locally with Spring?
